# Is it possible to expand multiple Jquery accordions within a single function and wait until all animations are complete?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using **jQuery UI 1.8**.

It has come to my attention that Jquery animations are asynchronous.  I think this is a problem for me because I have a page with a Jquery accordion that contains several sections.  When the page loads, I call a Javascript function that expands some of these sections.  They animate as they expand (ie, expand slowy).

Also on the page's startup is a function that uses Jquery to scroll to a particular element on the page.  It does not work by itself, and I think I've narrowed it down to the accordion's animations.  I theorize this because, when I use `window.setTimeout(myScrollFunction, 3000)` to call the function that performs the scroll, it works.  It's almost as if the animations are keeping the page from scrolling which sort of makes sense.

I've heard of the `.promise()` function, but I am thinking it might not work for me here.  What I need to do is execute function that expands the accordion sections, but wait until all animations invoked within it are finished before moving on to the next function.

I can't paste code samples and creating a test case would be complicated and time-consuming, so I am hoping I explained my situation clear enough to get some good answers.

**Conceptual example:**

I'll do this to give you a better idea of what I want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //I want to call ExpandSections() on startup
    ExpandSections(); 

    //but I don't want to call ScrollToElement() until 
    //all accordion sections that were expanded in ExpandSections()
    //have finished expanding.
    ScrollToElement(); 
});

function ExpandSections(){
    element1.accordion("option", "active", 0);
    element2.accordion("option", "active", 0);
    element3.accordion("option", "active", 0);
}

function ScrollToElement() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ElementToScrollTo.offset().top
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my example, have you seen/tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the accordion's [change/accordionchange](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/accordion/#event-change) event.

Here I've waited to bind the scroll event until just before the last active option is triggered.

Example:

```
function scrollToElement($el) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $el.offset().top
    }, 1);
}

function expandSections() {
    var $acc = $('#accordion');
    $acc.on('accordionchange', function (event, ui) {
        scrollToElement($('#scroll-to-me'));
    });
    $acc.accordion("option", "active", 2);
}
$(function () {
    var ac = $("#accordion").accordion({
        animated: 'swing', duration: 2000
    });
    expandSections();
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VyzPg/1/

Comment: I got it to sort of work.  The problem is that, after I activate my section (Section A) and then scroll to it, the other panels expand as expected via the `activate` event which pushes Section A off the screen since it's below the other panels.  I cannot modify the expansion of those default panels for reasons too complicated to explain.

Comment: I think what I really need is what I talked about in my question which is to apply this functionality to `expandSections` function itself so that it waits until all expansions within it are completed.  Also, I'll point out that I am using Jquery 1.8.16 and cannot upgrade, so I have to use `change` instead of `activate`.

Comment: Since the accordion can only display one open section at a time, why does `expandSections` contain three expansions right in a row like that?

Comment: The accordion I am using supports multiple (`jQuery UI Accordion 1.8.16` from the .js file).  Edit:  I once heard that it doesn't, so I guess it's possible that the prior developers modified it somehow to support multiple.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin see my updated answer and fiddle targeted to jQUI 1.8

Comment: I don't think this is going to work.  As I stated in my first comment to this answer, I cannot modify the code that expands the default panels on startup.  I need to apply this "animation complete" logic to the JS function that has the JS code that expands them, not attach an event to each panel using Jquery.  I guess I am essentially looking for a "wait until all Jquery animations are complete" function.  Thanks for your help (especially with jsfiddle), but I am thinking I am going to have to just wait for X seconds before scrolling.